# How to setup an iOS 17 interactive Widget using AppIntents from an SPM package?

Tags: widgetkit, xcode15, appintents, ios17

I've setup an interactive Widget in iOS 17 which uses an AppIntent from an SPM package but nothing works when you tap on the button in the widget.

Supposedly you should be able to use `AppIntentsPackage`, which should make it possible to use AppIntents from other frameworks/SPM package(?), but I cannot get it to work. This is my setup:

**SPMPackage**

```
public struct MyAppIntent: AppIntent { ... }

public struct MyAppIntentPackage: AppIntentsPackage { }
```

**WidgetExtension**

```
import SPMPackage

struct MyWidgetEntryView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(intent: MyAppIntent()) {
            Text("Tap here")
        }
        .containerBackground(...)
    }
}

extension MyWidgetBundle: AppIntentsPackage {
    static var includedPackages: [AppIntentsPackage.Type] = [
        MyAppIntentPackage.self
    ]
}
```

Seems to have set it up exactly how Apple explains it in the documentation but it doesn't work. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Got word back from an Apple representative that having AppIntents in an SPM package is not yet supported.

I solved my issue by moving all the code related to AppIntents in to the WidgetExtension and now it works reliably.

Hope this helps someone else in the future, but more hopeful that this will be resolved in a future iOS version.

Comment: I've been trying to do exactly this, I want to share the intent and TimelineProvider between widgets for phone and watch. Is there anyway to share code here?